# Rubymine not executing code inside first Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I've inherited a Rails application, and I'd like to add some unit tests (currently there were just a couple old broken capybara tests). I'm new to Rails so I want to start somewhere very basic. I have a users_controller.rb file, and I've added /test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb with the following code:

```
require "test_helper"

  puts "right before the test"

  def test_view_user_info
    puts "inside of the test"

    get "/users/12/edit"
    assert_response :success
  end
```

test_helper.rb just has:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

To run the test in Rubymine, I right-click the test select "Run 'Run test 'users_cont...' (and I also get the same result when I run 'rake test')

**The problem**: I get exit code 0, but we don't appear to run the code inside the test! I confirmed with with the 'puts' statements- the output only shows the one outside of the test, and not the one inside:

```
/Users/drkaplan/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest /Users/drkaplan/broad-count-me-in/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb
right before the test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I showed it to someone experienced with Rails who has never seen this before: it's as if my test file is being run as a script and not invoking the test blocks. The gemfile does include capybara in the test group (and I've added mintiest-rails for this new test) so I'm wondering if there may be some conflict between the two that prevents my test code from executing. Here's the relevant part of my gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
end
```

Another weird symptom: when I try running the test individually with --help, I get only the output from puts statements around the test, and none of the typical help options

```
ruby -I test  test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb --help
```

Anyone see what the problem may be, or had this symptom before?

Comment: can you update test_helper.rb with this content `require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
`

Comment: Thanks Vishal! I was intentionally leaving out fixtures at first to keep things as simple as possible. Are fixtures necessary for tests in Rails?

Comment: What if you run from the terminal, and not rubymine?

Comment: `Fixtures are a way of organizing data that you want to test against; in short, sample data.`

Comment: thanks @SergioTulentsev! Unfortunately I have the same results when I run 'rake test' in the terminal: I see my output from before the test but not from inside it. 

@Vishal: Fixtures had sounded like a useful but optional tool- is this actually required in order for Rails to execute the code inside the 'test' block? (I'll try adding it now, just want to understand what's happening)

Comment: @DianeKaplan: I myself don't use minitest, but that `test do` looks like a DSL. Don't you have to enable it specifically (by including some module or flipping some option)? What if you use a regular ruby method, `def test_view_user_info`?

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev- the symptoms are exactly the same when I try it as a regular ruby method. It appears that my test file is running like a script and not actually invoking any of the tests. I'm noticing that the Gemfile had specified capybara as well, so I'm wondering if it's having a conflict with minitest. I'll update the description with details

Comment: @DianeKaplan: [readme suggests](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) you have to `require 'minitest/autorun'`

Comment: Thank you, @SergioTulentsev! Yes, now I see that Rails has a lot of different gems out there for testing, each with their specific setup needs. Looking closer now at what's in the Gemfile and test_helper.rb and making the necessary adjustments, now the code in my tests is executing. Thank you!